# Custom app installed onto Galaxy Nexus doesn't look anything like it should

Tags: android, user-interface, android-emulator

I am developing an app in Android that I hope to release. I've got most of my GUI done, but it does not look even close to correct on the device when installed and opened. I have a screenshot of how it looks, and a screengrab of how it should look (taken from the Emulator in Eclipse) at the links at the bottom of this post. It's best to take a look at the two images rather than me try to describe how screwed up the app becomes on my device.

I had a friend with the exact same device, including hardware and Android version, and his loads up just fine. Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? Both devices are Galaxy Nexuses, running Android 4.0.2, GSM on AT&T (unlocked).

Installed on my device: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x66Jo.png
In the emulator: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE0J6.png

Comment: Just wanted to add that changing my Android manifest didn't help. Specifically, I removed the line: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"

That line shuts off the title bar for the app. With the line on, there's no title bar in the emu, with it removed, the title bar returns. Interestingly, the app does look slightly differently on the device once installed without that line. There's a couple horizontal white pixels on the left middle of the screen. Could this be some ridiculous scaling issue on the device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this occur in some Galaxy Nexus' and I put it down to a bug/glitch in the OS on that Galaxy Nexus. Try a Factory Reset of your Galaxy Nexus, if that fails, try reinstalling the current OS version you have (if you can get your hands on it), if that fails, get it fixed under warranty.

Comment: I will back up some critical items on my phone and get back to you ASAP. I tried Triad's suggestion about Dev Options and it did not work. Good thing I haven't rooted this particular phone just yet, I will at least be able to get it repaired/replaced while still under warranty. Thanks!

Comment: Also worth checking if your phone has an update available, as that can fix the problem (a "corrupt" update can also create the problem it seems).

Comment: I can't vote you up, because I have too little rep. Either way, a factory reset + reinstallation of my APK solved the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Actually Straya, I was on the most up to date version, 4.0.2 - AT&T hasn't pushed out 4.0.3. The reset that I performed kept me at 4.0.2

Answer (score 1):

Does your app use multiple activities?

Can you compare on your two devices if this setting is the same?

Settings > Developer Options > Don't keep activities checkbox.

Comment: My app will use multiple activities. The files are even create, but my onCreate is entirely commented out except for:

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

In order to bugtest why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is an old question now but I was having the same problem as you and stumbled across a solution. I didn't particularly want to factory reset my phone as per straya's instructions, so I started playing around options in the Settings > Developer Options menu.

As it turns out, this problem occurs for some applications if you have the `Force GPU rendering` option checked. Disable this (I'm not sure why it was enabled anyway) and everything displays as it should.

Comment: Interesting. Obviously the other solution worked fine, so I don't actually need to test this - but if it comes up again, I'll try that!

Comment: I doubt that's the reason, since this problem is intermittent between phones that are in the same state. I.e. get a whole bunch of new Galaxy Nexus phones (because you can afford a whole bunch), they'll all basically be in the same state, same settings, the "factory" state but one or two might manifest this problem.